# Разделение строки в массив

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как решить задачу, мне нужно разбить строку в массив:

```
    $s = "бла бла бла Сила+5 бла бла бла Ловкость+12 бла бла бла Шанс-2";
```

разделителем я хотел сделать пробел которому предшествует цифры:

```
    $a = preg_split("/\d+\s+/", $s);
```

но так я отсекаю сами числа которые мне нужны.

- бла бла бла Сила+
- бла бла бла Ловкость+
- бла бла бла Шанс-

Comment: В принципе, вы могли в свой код просто добавить ключ \K - ` $a = preg_split("/\d+\K\s+/", $s);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться ретроспективной проверкой

```
<?php
$s = "бла бла бла Сила+5 бла бла бла Ловкость+12 бла бла бла Шанс-2";
$a = preg_split("/(?<=[0-9])\s+/", $s);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Как работает: https://repl.it/Ce7W/0